# Define one SQLAlchemy model to be related to one of multiple other models

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm designing the database for my own Q&A website, which is somewhat similar to Stack Overflow:

1. A "question" can have several "answers", but an "answer" has only one "question".
2. Both "questions" and "answers" can have several "comments", but a "comment" has only one "question" or "answer".

I have no idea how to design such a database. Here is what I've tried:

```
class Question(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'questions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.Unicode(64), unique=True)
    body = db.Column(db.UnicodeText)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    answers = db.relationship('Answer', backref='question', lazy='dynamic')

class Answer(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'answers'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.UnicodeText)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    question_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('questions.id'))

class Comment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('')) ???
```

Comment: For a simple implementation, you might consider having `QuestionComment` and `AnswerComment` as separate entities, rather than putting them into a single entity.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for the reply. In fact, I've considered that before. Alternatively, I could merge `Question` and `Answer` to `Post`, which have a boolean field called `is_question`. However, I want to find a more "elegant" approach.

Comment: The design looks rather fine...

Answer (score 3):

So you've already managed the first point.

What you're looking for is a generic relationship. You can find it in [`sqlalchemy_utils`](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package.

```
from sqlalchemy_utils import generic_relationship


class Comment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    object_type = db.Column(db.Unicode(255))
    object_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    object = generic_relationship(object_type, object_id)
```

[Docs](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generic_relationship.html) for generic relationship

So basically what it does, it stores the `object_type` as answer or question and `object_id` as object's primary key.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you extract a base class for Question and Answer, e.g. Post, and make Comment relate to Post, such that a Post can have multiple Comments.

SQLAlchemy ORM supports few strategies to [implement inheritance in the database](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html), and the right strategy to choose depends on the way you plan to query your entities. Here's the [detailed documentation on how to properly configure it](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/inheritance.html).

So you'd get something like this:

*(disclaimer: I have not directly ran this code, but composed it from your example, and my own code. If it ain't working for you, let me know and I'll fix)*

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    kind = Column(db.Unicode(64), nullable=False)
    body = db.Column(db.UnicodeText)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='post', lazy='dynamic')

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'posts',
        'polymorphic_on': kind
    }

class Question(Post):
    __tablename__ = 'questions'

    title = db.Column(db.Unicode(64), unique=True)
    answers = db.relationship('Answer', backref='question', lazy='dynamic')

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'questions',
    }

class Answer(Post):
    __tablename__ = 'answers'

    question_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('questions.id'))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'answers',
    }

class Comment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.id'))
```